# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. By reading captcha with using tr repository

Tags: django, window, python-3.6

I am using tr --> https://github.com/myhub/tr (this repository to read captcha). I am getting an errorr **WinError 193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application**. I have installed **tr** repository in my env as per the instruction mentioned in this repository. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered this question on Github Issues.
It was in chinese but I translated it:

> I found the reason why python is installed with a 64-bit system, and
> 32-bit python is required to do QAQ

Comment: I also installed 32-bit python but it didn't work.